# What is TAPS in this report?

Tags: easa, terminology, carbon-footprint, emissions

In researching for [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/7582/flight-pollution-on-take-off), I came across some [reports](http://www.easa.europa.eu/system/files/dfu/11GE139%20-%20GEnx-2B67%20TAPS%20%2809.04.2013%29.pdf) from EASA referring to TAPS. What is the meaning of TAPS in this context?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TAPS means **Twin Annular Premixing Swirler**, a cyclone mixer / combuster designed to keep the NO<sub>x</sub> emissions of the General Electric GEnx engines low.
[image]

source: [FAA report](http://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/apl/research/aircraft_technology/cleen/reports/media/TAPS_II_Public_Final_Report.pdf)

[AIAA report](http://arc.aiaa.org/doi/abs/10.2514/6.2012-936)