# What is a TAPS combustor and how does it differ from any other annular combustor?

Tags: jet-engine

I found out that [the GEnx engine](https://www.geaviation.com/commercial/engines/genx-engine) uses a TAPS (Twin Annular Premixing Swirler) combustor. Is it a single or dual annular combustor ?

Comment: Probably a duplicate of your other question: [What is the difference between single and dual annular combustor?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/44869/3201). As you don't have yet selected an answer, you could just request about TAPS particularity in the same post.

Answer (score 1):

See [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/7595/what-is-taps-in-this-report).  It is a single annular combustor (one ring of full nozzles).  I think that "twin" refers to the fact that within a single fuel nozzle, there are two different fuel streams: the main stream and the pilot stream.  [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y8QqX6q6RSk) might also help explain it a bit.